# How to create a recursive queue?

Tags: rust, dynamic, traits

I am trying to implement a recursive queue using the `trait Element<T>` as a container for all the functions of the different nodes of the queue and two structs implementing it called `Node<T>` and `End`.

The `Node<T>` struct is supposed to handle all the functionality within the queue itself and the `End` struct's purpose is to deal with the case of the last node.

I've got the following code:

```rust
trait Element<T> {
    fn append_item(self, item: T) -> Node<T>;
}

struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    successor: Box<dyn Element<T>>
}

impl<T> Element<T> for Node<T> {
    fn append_item(mut self, item: T) -> Node<T> {
        self.successor = Box::new(self.successor.append_item(item));
        self
    }
}

struct End;

impl<T> Element<T> for End {
    fn append_item(self, item: T) -> Node<T> {
        Node { data: item, successor: Box::new(self) }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I get two errors:

1. *Cannot move a value of type `dyn Element<T>`*
2. *The parameter type `T` may not live long enough*

both on the same line in `Node::append_item`.

Now, I get why the first error occurs (because the size of `dyn Element<T>` cannot be statically determined) but I don't know how to work around it and I have no idea why the second error occurs.

Comment: I'd say the interface is all messed up. I wouldn't use traits, I'd use an enum. I'd have `append_item` take a mutable reference to self instead of ownership.

Comment: If I let `append_item` take a mutable reference to self I lose the ability to return (owned) self and thus I can't return a new Node in `End::append_item`

Comment: Your code doesn't look right to me. In `append_item()`, doesn't a new Node need to be created? `successor` is initialized with `Box::new()` but inside the Box we're trying to refer to `successor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Frxstrem already elaborated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75377632/442760) how to get around the need to move by using `Box<Self>` as receiver. If you need more flexibility in the parameter type (i.e. be able to hold on to references as well as owned types) instead of requiring `T: 'static` you can introduce a named lifetime:

```rust
trait Element<'a, T: 'a> {
    fn append_item(self: Box<Self>, item: T) -> Node<'a, T>;
}

struct Node<'a, T: 'a> {
    data: T,
    successor: Box<dyn Element<'a, T> + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> Element<'a, T> for Node<'a, T> {
    fn append_item(self: Box<Self>, new_data: T) -> Node<'a, T> {
        Node {
            successor: Box::new(self.successor.append_item(new_data)),
            ..*self
        }
    }
}

struct End;

impl<'a, T: 'a> Element<'a, T> for End {
    fn append_item(self: Box<Self>, data: T) -> Node<'a, T> {
        Node {
            data,
            successor: self,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type `dyn Element<T>`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:35
   |
12 |         self.successor = Box::new(self.successor.append_item(item));
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the size of `dyn Element<T>` cannot be statically determined
```

The issue here is that `fn append_item(self, item: T)` takes `self` by value, but in this case `self` has type `dyn Element<T>`, which is unsized and can therefore never be passed by value.

The easiest solution here is to just take `self: Box<Self>` instead. This means that this method is defined on a `Box<E>` instead of directlThis will work perfectly fine with trait objects like `dyn Element<T>`, and it does not require the type to be sized.

(Additionally, in the updated code below, I've changed the return type to `Box<Node<T>>` for convenience, but this is not required per se, just a bit more convenient.)

```rust
trait Element<T> {
    fn append_item(self: Box<Self>, item: T) -> Box<Node<T>>;
}

impl<T> Element<T> for Node<T> {
    fn append_item(mut self: Box<Self>, item: T) -> Box<Node<T>> {
        self.successor = self.successor.append_item(item);
        self
    }
}

impl<T> Element<T> for End {
    fn append_item(self: Box<Self>, item: T) -> Box<Node<T>> {
        Box::new(Node { data: item, successor: self })
    }
}
```

[[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d001f258d4206d4d5ddcdcbace8e3077)]

---

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:12:26
   |
12 |         self.successor = Box::new(self.successor.append_item(item));
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
```

The issue here is that `dyn Trait` has an implicit lifetime. In reality, it's `dyn '_ + Trait`. What exactly that lifetime is depends on the context, and you can read [the exact rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes) in the Rust reference, but if neither the containing type nor the trait itself has any references, then the lifetime will always be `'static`.

This is the case with `Box<dyn Element<T>>`, which really is `Box<dyn 'static + Element<T>>`. In other words, whatever type is contained by the `Box` must have a `'static` lifetime. For this to be the case for `Node<T>`, it must also be that `T` has a `'static` lifetime.

This is easy to fix, though: just follow the compiler's suggestion to add a `T: 'static` bound:

```rust
impl<T: 'static> Element<T> for Node<T> {
//    ^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

[[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0db46d3dd9cb9f502cb61993d191f06e))